# Can you trade from Pokemon Sun to Moon, X to Y, etc

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-seventh-generation

My friend has Pokemon Sun and I'm most likely gonna get Moon, would we be able to trade, battle/interact with each other with different variations of the game?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** - Games within the same generation can trade with one another:

- Pokemon X can trade with Pokemon Y
- Pokemon Sun can trade with Pokemon Moon

Do note that Pokemon X/Y (Generation 6) cannot trade directly with Pokemon Sun/Moon (Generation 7). It is possible to transfer Pokemon from X/Y up to Sun/Moon, but this is a one-way transfer, not a trade.